# Slice characters from all array items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, slice

I have an array

```
myArray = ['A123000','A234000','A456000']
```

I want to slice out the first 4 characters from each array item, so the output looks like this:

```
['A123','A234','A456']
```

I tried this but it doesn't like array -  Am I missing an each or something? Help!

```
myArray.slice(0,3);
```

Comment: Yes, you'll have to iterate through each element of the array. You could use `.map()` for example to make a new array with the new sliced strings.

Comment: `myArray.map(e=>e.slice(0,4))`

Answer (score 3):

Use the same `slice` within `map` for each element

```
var output = myArray.map( s => s.slice(0,4) )
```

or with `substring`

```
var output = myArray.map( s => s.substring(0,4) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let myArray = ['A123000','A234000','A456000'];

let newArray = myArray.map(a => a.slice(0,4) );

console.log( newArray );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.map` and then use `.substring` on each element

```js
var arr = ['A123000','A234000','A456000'];
var sliced = arr.map(el => el.substring(0, 4));
console.log(sliced);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```js
    let myArray = ['A123000','A234000','A456000'];
    
    result = myArray.map(a => a.slice(0,4) );
    console.log( result );
```